# No response on channels endpoint

Tags: youtube-data-api

When we use the access token granted for [an ID of a youtube user account] with the query below

endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels

parameters: {‘access_token’: [redacted], ‘mine’: True, ‘quotaUser’: ‘managed’, ‘part’: ‘id,snippet’, ‘type’: ‘channel’}

We receive a no-result response despite the ‘mine’: True parameter

Despite the user being an owner of the channel.

endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels

parameters: {‘access_token’: [redacted], ‘mine’: True, ‘quotaUser’: ‘managed’, ‘part’: ‘id,snippet’, ‘type’: ‘channel’}